# Cannot deploy grails war in Tomcat 7 and Ubuntu - 404 error

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04, grails-3.0

I've create a simple Grails 3 application to test the issue with deploying to Tomcat on Ubuntu server (Digital Ocean).

To create the app :

```
grails create-app test
```

To ensure tomcat is not embedded in the deployed WAR :

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

To create the WAR

grails war

I'm then uploading and deploying the WAR using the Tomcat Application Manager.

The App Manager reports the application is successfully deployed.

Catalina.out reports finding the app and explodes the WAR.

However, visiting `http://ipaddress:8080/test` results in 404

I've deployed an sample war file (from tomcat 6) and the sample app deploys without an issue and I can access it on `http://ipaddress:8080/sample`

So the difference is specifically between a Grails (3) war and a more typical war.

Deploying the test war/app works on my local installation of Tomcat perfectly (Mac OS) but not on the Ubuntu server.

I've seen a number of similar problems on this issue but none have provided a working solution.

One thing I notice that I don't see (that I do in my local environment) is the h2 database : prodDb.h2.db

My guess is startup is failing but I can't find any logs detailing the errors...

Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to add, if I pull in index.html and/or hello.jp from the sample app into the grails application (test), index.html and hello.jsp both resolve/execute and are served normally.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I see the same in my environment.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I gave up on Digital Ocean and went with Heroku for deployment and I've not looked back.  Zero server management is the way forward for me at least as I've no interest in the setup and management of servers and security.  Good luck.